# OpenGL lights and deferred shading

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader, light, deferred-rendering

Is it fair to say that the only difference between directional lights and point lights is that directional lights have no attenuation factor?
Also, do most games use deferred shading? Should I implement deferred shading in my application if I use say less than 10 lights overall?

Comment: Point lights are lightbulbs, they cast light radially **around** them.  Directional lights are like the sun, they cast **directionally**.  If you were to put a point light inside a sphere, it would illuminate all faces within that sphere, a point light would only illuminate those faces whose normals were opposite the direction of the light (half of the sphere).  The rest of your question might be better asked on [Game Dev StackExchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it fair to say that the only difference between directional lights
>   and point lights is that directional lights have no attenuation
>   factor?

If you model directional lights as point lights which are indefinitely far away, the attenuation is indeed the only difference.

> Also, do most games use deferred shading?

Yes, most games do use deferred shading.

> Should I implement deferred shading in my application if I use say
>   less than 10 lights overall?

My personal suggestion is to use deferred shading if you have 2 or more light sources.